# How do I make my repository show python symbol?

Tags: github

How do I get my repository to show the python symbol like the below?

[image]

Comment: Commit python code.

Comment: I do not understand what you mean @RobbyCornelissen

The code is already in the repository. I have the report in pdf and a readme file with the code

Comment: What's currently in your repository?

Comment: put python code in the repository. Aren't these symbols automatic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the beginning, you must commit and push your project to your repo. **Most** of your project must consist of python. GitHub will automatically assign the symbol to your repository.